# How to calculate progress of MBProgressHUD mode when used with NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mbprogresshud

I am trying to use MBProgressHUD with NSURLConnection, but I'm not sure how to make the animation spin in `MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate`.

Basically I have this code in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self fetchFromServer];

    self.HUD = [ [MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    self.HUD.labelText = @"Loading Schedule...";
    [self.view addSubview:self.HUD];
    self.HUD.dimBackground = YES;
    [self.HUD show:YES];
}
```

When this view is loaded, I call a method to fetch from the database. I want MBProgressHUD to load. Then I want it to end once the data has been fetched.

```
- (void)fetchFromServer
{

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"url.com"];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[ [NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[ [NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

         NSArray *jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                   options:0 error:&error];

             scheduleJSONArray = jsonObj;

             // Progress in HUD should end here after scheduleJSONArray is set

             [self.HUD hide:YES];
      } ];
}
```

I don't know what to use to update the progress of HUD. Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You have to add the progress yourself. It isn't autonomous

Answer (score 1):

You better use **AFNetworking**:

```
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
// Set up HUD 

__weak ViewController *weakSelf = self;
NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"url.com" parameters:nil error:nil];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
__weak AFHTTPRequestOperation *weakOperation = operation;
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
  [weakSelf updateHUDForOpetation:weakOperation
                       totalBytes:totalBytesExpectedToRead
                        readBytes:totalBytesRead
                            index:[videoNames indexOfObject:videoName]
                            total:videoNames.count];
}];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
}];
```

Then update HUD manually. Like this:

```
- (void)updateHUDTotalBytes:(long long)totalBytes
                  readBytes:(long long)readBytes {
  MBProgressHUD *HUD = [MBProgressHUD HUDForView:self.view];
  HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate;
  HUD.labelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld/%lld", readBytes / 1024, totalBytes / 1024];
  HUD.progress = (double)readBytes / (double)totalBytes;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the code at all, the first part. How can I use this code with my current implementation? Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: @Pangu, you need to use AFNetworking framework to use progressive download functionality. Google it.

Comment: @orkenstein you're above comment sounds as if it's mandatory, which is false. You don't _need_ to use AFNetworking framework it can be done with `NSURLConnection` as the OP as asked, but you have to add the delegates and progress bytes (something you hinted at in your bytes example). Your comments could be confusing to future question seekers with little coding experience

Comment: @soulshined, my solution was based on AFNetworking, so it requires it.
You can write your own answer.

Comment: I understand, I'm just saying for future question seekers that aren't particularly experienced with this topic, your comment reads roughly awkward "you need to use AFNetowrking framework to use progressive download functionality" which isn't true, you can use progress calls anywhere. No biggie though. Reading comments will sort it out hopefully. Good answer for those that using AFNetworking though, OP is not

Comment: @soulshined I think he did a great job and the given code is the correct answer. be grateful or if you think you have a better answer please go write it.

Comment: I did say it was a great answer @bader don't selectively comprehend what you want. There is no reason for me to write an answer because of said statement. This is a community to help others and we both did that --